# Authenticate with Django 1.5

Tags: django

i'm currently testing django 1.5 and it custom USer model, but i've some understanding problems
i've created a User class in my account app, which looks like :

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField()
    activation_key = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

i can corectly register a user, who is stored in my account_user table.
Now, how can i log in ?
I've tried with

```
def login(request):
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
        email =  request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password'] 
        user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(user)
            else:
                message = 'disabled account, check validation email'
                return render(
                        request, 
                        'account-login-failed.html', 
                        {'message': message}
                )
    return render(request, 'account-login.html', {'form': form})
```

but user is None the it render the login form :(
Why my autheticate returns me None ?
Any idea ?

forms.py

```
class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """ a form to create user"""
    password = forms.CharField(
            label="Password",
            widget=forms.PasswordInput()
    )
    password_confirm = forms.CharField(
            label="Password Repeat",
            widget=forms.PasswordInput()
    )
    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = ('last_login', 'activation_key')

    def clean_password_confirm(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
        password_confirm = self.cleaned_data.get("password_confirm")
        if password and password_confirm and password != password_confirm:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Password don't math")
        return password_confirm

    def clean_email(self):
        if User.objects.filter(email__iexact=self.cleaned_data.get("email")):
            raise forms.ValidationError("email already exists")
        return self.cleaned_data['email']

    def save(self):
        user = super(RegisterForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.password = self.cleaned_data['password']
        user.activation_key = generate_sha1(user.email)
        user.save()

        return user
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen after you call `login()` with the new user?

Comment: it's not the question, a render() i guess with a session opened.

Comment: It completely *is* the question. You call login, then... nothing. You just drop down to the last line, where it renders the login form again. If you want to do something else, you'll need to actually put some code in to do something else.

Comment: for this moment i try to understand why authenticate gives me None

Comment: @DanielRoseman authenticate() is returning None according to the OP so he is not even getting to login()

Comment: @barbie are you using a custom manager that extends BaseUserManager?

Comment: @César nope, i don't, i create user with my RegisterForm, like exposed in my post update. I really don't understand what is the manager aim :(

Comment: You try to validate your form data first with if form.is_valid(). If the user you get is None, maybe there is a problem with the input and POST data.

Comment: @Jingo there is no problem with my post datas, it's what i expect. I'm just asking why "user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)" gives me None. i think i don't use it as usual, bu i don't find my error

Comment: @barbie like I said, I believe this has something to do with the user manager. Have you tried that?

Comment: I've added a manager like explain in the official document but nothing MORELE i think i've miss smtg. What this manager is supposed to do ? I never enter into the creater _user methods

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/#customizing-the-user-model) has a really good example of using the new custom user.

From your code the only thing I see missing is the custom authentication backend.

I have a file named auth.py. The methods "authenticate" and "get_user" are required.

```
from models import User as CustomUser

class CustomAuth(object):

    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            user = CustomUser.objects.get(email=username)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            user = CustomUser.objects.get(pk=user_id)
            if user.is_active:
                return user
            return None
        except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Then the authentication backends have to be specified in your settings file

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('apps.accounts.auth.CustomAuth')
```

Comment: If you're using AbstractBaseUser, is it necessary to create a custom authentication backend?  Can't we still use the one at `django.contrib.auth.authenticate` [[code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/backends.py#L11)], as it relies on `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`?  I don't see that this version does anything different than that one.  Does it?

Comment: You would probably want to subclass `ModelBackend`: `class CustomAuth(ModelBackend)`